# Unique Header File Code: Is it valid

Tags: c++, syntax, header

I have come across a C++ Header file written by someone else and it has some coding conventions that I have never seen before. Is the following code valid in a header file and if so what is this technique called and why do you use it?

```
#if 0
    int test()
        return values = 0
                      = 1

#endif
```

Note how theres no semi colon, no curly brackets and that values is not defined anywhere previously in the header file.

Comment: Well, it's "commented" out, so sure it's valid.

Comment: Where is it commented out? I dont see any comment characters(// or /*)

Comment: `#if 0 ` menas comment out, compiler ignores such code

Comment: Just as a tidbit, this is a popular choice to comment out large blocks of code because `/* */` comments cannot be nested (and so you can't use them to comment out a block of code that contains one).

Comment: @FatalError thanks I really needed to know why someone would use this instead of conventional comments and noone was answering me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called commented code.
`#if 0` comments out all the code that follows till an `#endif` is encountered.

Perhaps someone started with some pseudo code and then left it for future.

Good Read:
**[#IF ... #ENDIF Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyscbeay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Comment: Why wouldn't the programmer use standard comments, ie, `/* */`. Is this an old way of doing comments, ie using pre-compiler commands?

Comment: @JakeM It's the moral equivalent of a comment. #if conditionally includes its body, and since the condition is `0`.. then yes, it's a comment.

Comment: @JakeM: The link inline to the answer should help you understand better.

Answer (score 1):

This code will never get executed. The `#if 0` says, *when 0 is true, put the following chunk of code in the final file*. Since 0 is always false, this code is effectively commented out.

```
int main(){
    #if 0
    lfaksjdf;lakjf;alskdjfa;lsdjf
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

is totally legal.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if 0
    anything you want
#endif
```

The '#if 0' is a way to comment out code. It tells the preprocessor to not include anything between the #if and #endif.

So that is just some pseudo code and need not be valid.